# How to convert Point Cloud Library meshes to GLTF file in iOS

Tags: swift, xcode, mesh, point-cloud-library, gltf

We try develop an app just like 3d Scanner and use Point Cloud Library (PCL) to generate mesh.

We want to export result mesh to GLTF (GLB) file, but PCL only supported obj, pcd, ply, stl.

How can I export GLTF (GLB) on device?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: For the best we search solution which can convert obj to GLTF, or convert PCL mesh to GLTF, for the backup, we consider use online gltf converter.

Comment: For now I can't find any appropriate solution to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Finally we use [ASSIMP](https://github.com/assimp/assimp) as library in our app, when PCL export obj file, use [ASSIMP](https://github.com/assimp/assimp) convert the obj file to GLB file,  [document](https://assimp-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/use_the_lib.html#exporting-models) about exporting models.

Here is steps how to use ASSIMP in Xcode:

1. git clone https://github.com/assimp/assimp.git
2. cd assimp/port/iOS/
3. ./build.sh
4. after that, you have "libassimp.a" in assimp/lib/iOS/arm64(we preferred arm64)
5. create folder named "assimpLib" in Xcode and copy libassimp.a and assimp/include folder(header files) in it.
6. add path for the assimpLib in Header Search Path in Xcode Build setting, just like $(PROJECT_DIR)/MY_PROJECT/assimpLib
7. setting all done, now you can write a c++ wrapper file call ASSIMP function via swift.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I guess what they want to know is how you did? Did you use ASSIMP in iOS - I checked their repo and all their sample code is quite old. Curious to hear how you got it to work in iOS. It looks like a great library so keen to hear how you did it.

Comment: @DanM, thanks, I just edit the answer

Comment: Is this fairly common using ASSIMP? It even loads .blend files, pretty crazy. What kind of features have you been using from it?

Comment: I can't find other solution for now, We only use exporting model feature to do the job convert from obj file to glb file, if you have any good idea, please let me know, very appreciate it.